# Data set for predictive/preventive manufacturing

Tags: azure, machine-learning, dataset, prediction

I'm eager to try out some more with Microsoft Azure Machine Learning and would like to find a data set to make a use case concerning predictive manufacturing. Microsoft already offers a data set (semi conductor) for a use case like this, but I would like to try out some more. Does anybody of you know where I can find another data set similiar to the one provided by MS?

Basically I'm looking for a bunch of sensor data in a manufacturing process and a classification whether it came to a failure or not.

Your help would be greatly appreciated ;)
Thanks,

Clemens

Comment: Maybe this question should be migrated to http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2015/03/30/getting-interesting-data-into-azure-machine-learning-azureml.aspx) contains interesting sources of data that you can use with Azure ML.  From the post:

> Data.gov – http://www.data.gov/
>   Kaggle - http://www.kaggle.com/
>   UCI Machine Learning Repository - http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/

Specifically, you could check out the [manufacturing data set](http://www.data.gov/manufacturing/) on data.gov.